# Handle the "no choice" in a radiobutton group

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I have the following problem. 
I have a radiogroup with 3 radiobuttons. None of them is selected as default.
I also have a button.
Pressing the button my application does something according to which radiobutton is selected.
If no radiobutton is selected my app crashes. 
I use switch - case.
Can i override the problem without using try-catch statements? 
Thanks.

Note: I tried implementing my logic in the "default: " section of the switch loop with no success.

Edit. 
Below is my switch statement. You asked for it...

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int checkedId) {

                switch (spot_chooser) {
                case 0:
                                         theString10 = "hello";

                    break;
                case 1:
                    theString10 = "yo";

                    break;
                case 2:
                    theString10 = "treeeno";

                    break;
                default:
                    theString10 = "pick me";
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you put some piece of code..!!!

Comment: one more way to do is to add "none" item in radio group...!!!

Comment: @RushabhPatel More exclamation marks please

Comment: Well i cannot think of a way to do this since it is a radiobutton not a dropdown list

Comment: Please post your `switch` statement so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Boolean check = false;
        Button YourButton;

               RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);

                btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                                    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
    switch (isChecked) {
                    case 0:
                        theString10 = "hello";
                        check = isChecked;

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        theString10 = "yo";
      check = isChecked;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        theString10 = "treeeno";
      check = isChecked;
                        break;

                    }
}
}); 


        YourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (check == false) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "please check the radiobutton", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        /// toast here please check the radiobutton

                        } else {
                            //////
        do your work 
        Toast.makeText(this, theString10 , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not the kind of behaviour i need

Comment: ok i got what you want wait i'll upload the answer but my answer fulfill your first need

Comment: Check it may be it helps